# parent child class conversion with generic type

Tags: c#, .net

I have 3 classes named `OptionFeature`,`Fabric`,`Material`

`Fabric` is a child class of `Material`.

Now i have an object of type `OptionFeature<Fabric>` . How to convert this object into `OptionFeature<Material>`

Comment: Generic variance supported only for interfaces and delegates, not for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OptionFeature optionFeature = new OptionFeature();
            optionFeature.material = new Material();
            Fabric fabric = (Fabric)optionFeature.material;
            List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();
            List<Fabric> fabrics = materials.Select(x => (Fabric)x).ToList();


        }
    }
    public class OptionFeature
    {
        public Material material {get;set;}
    }
    public class Material
    {
    }
    public class Fabric : Material
    {
    }​
```